# How to protect against SQL Injection with OdbcCommand when the query is not parameterized?

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc

I am writing a generic sqldump utility that takes a DSN and a table name and dumps the contents to a file.  It's an internal app so SQL Injection is not a serious threat, but I don't want to have to worry about it.  The thing is, the variable part of the query is actually the tablename, so the query is going to look like:

```
select * from [tablename];
```

...which I don't imagine will work well with the OdbcCommand's parameterized query support.  I am also trying to support all types of DSN's as generically as I can, regardless of the driver on the other side of the DSN.

Is there some universal way to sanitize my `tablename` input to protect against all SQL Injection using the OdbcCommand object?

Comment: Due to the use of OdbcCommand, I am guessing this isnt specific to any particular DBMS?

Comment: Right, I'm trying to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Overall, a query strategy like this is generally a bad thing, whether you can get it to work or not. In addition to out-and-out injection attacks, a query like this used in your DAL could be used against a table with some several million rows, and the resulting DataReader will tie up both client and server for a VERY long time. "Select *" will also produce two different sets of columns when run before or after changing the column structure, which can cause unpredictable behavior. This is just a Very Bad Idea from beginning to end.

Comment: That is not a concern; as I said, this is an internal application and I will have a decent amount of control over what it's doing.  I don't see how this qualifies for the `Very Bad Idea` moniker for taking a while to do something that will take a while to do.  And truly, I'm not especially concerned about SQL Injection for the same reason, I just don't like writing code that's vulnerable to it if there's a reasonably elegant way to avoid doing so.  But I don't know what you mean about the two sets of columns... can you explain?

Comment: Quite simply, if you run a command "select * from MyTable" from your code, then parse out the results, you'll get the columns of each row in the order they are specified in the DB. The columns of a table can change; it's not an everyday occurrence but it happens regularly. In such a case, the number of columns, or their order, can change. Your code to parse out the query results may assume a constant number and/or arrangement of columns; in such cases a change to the schema will break your code in ways that can be difficult to catch and to debug.

Comment: The first reason I gave is generally the more pertinent; in an accounting system, "select * from GeneralLedger" returns a result set that is ALL of the GL transactions that have ever been made by the system since its inception. Your average midsize company could produce many thousands of GL transactions every day. That is a LOT of data; it could well require more memory to represent than is available to a .NET application, and very few situations would call for returning EVERY column of EVERY row in ANY table, meaning anything you don't need is wasted bandwidth and memory. It's just bad.

Comment: Ah, yes these are valid points, but precisely what I am trying to do.  As I stated, I am writing a sqldump to literally take all data in a table and move it to a text file... we have half a dozen vendors who are running analytics on these raw data feeds, so I'm making a console app to script out the dumps and ship them off, on a dedicated app server.  The `*` is absolutely vital for exactly the reason you described: the data can change, and I need to capture all of it.  Luckily, I am not the one consuming it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check the user input against the list of tables you know are there, using code roughly like what's posted [here](http://asadyousufi.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-get-list-of-tables-using-adonet.html) to retrieve the table list (code from the link included for posterity):

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
   // Connect to the database then retrieve the schema information.
   connection.Open();
   DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

   // Display the contents of the table.
   DisplayData(table);
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
   Console.ReadKey();
   }
 }
```

That said, I agree with @KeithS above.  This is probably a Bad Idea.

Comment: Just make sure there aren't any tables named: "'] drop table 'Users'" or some such or you'll have problem ;)

Comment: Sure- additional safety checks never hurt.

Comment: are all odbc database drivers required to support the GetSchema() method?

Comment: I believe so, but don't quote me on it. IIRC it's part of the ODBC api spec.

Comment: I ended up doing something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

If the table name is enclosed in `[` `]` then just do not allow table names to contain `"]"`. `]` could be used by malicious people to terminated the sql command and to introduce dangerous code.

If you are constructing the sql like this

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + tablename + "]";
```

and the `tablename` is defined like this

```
string tablename = "tablename]; DELETE FROM [tablename";
```

The resulting sql becomes

```sql
SELECT * FROM [tablename]; DELETE FROM [tablename];
```

However, this is only possible if the table name contains a `]`.

---

Note:

If you are replacing string values like this, then replacing a single quote by two single quotes makes it safe too.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Name = '" + input.Replace("'","''") + "'";
```

Comment: the brackets were just an example... most ODBC databases use other things (single quotes, double quotes, etc.)  Still, what you are describing is exactly what I am looking to prevent: Sql Injection.  It'd be pretty cool if parameterized queries supported "meta-parameters".

Comment: Disallow all known delimiters and of cause `;`, which is used to separate commands in SQL. Table names with this kind of characters are very unlikely to occur. Or more restrictive, allow only a predefined set of characters to occur `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could first query the information_schema to find out if the table exists:

```
select * 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = @your_database_name and table_name = @table_name
```

This query can be parameterized and is NOT prone to SQL injections.

Following that, you can issue your `select * from @table_name` query.

Comment: is the `information_schema.tables` object available in all ODBC data sources?

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres and SQLite support it as part of the ANSI standard. I am not sure about Oracle, though - I think it does not support it. There is a sourceforge.net [progect](http://database-geek.com/2009/04/30/oracle-information_schema) that add the information_schema views, but you can also use Oracle data dictionary instead. The way to go about it would be to use strategy pattern to issue "Table exist?" query that is specific to the ODBC provider detected using [ConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The only special character in a `[]` quoted identifier for SQL Server is `]`, and it can be escaped by passing `]]`. So for that, `"select * from [" + tableName.Replace("]", "]]") + "];"` should be safe. Other systems, however, may use other escape mechanisms, so this is not a full solution if you want to connect to a different type of database.

Alternatively, consider each character, and see if it is a valid character for table names you wish to support. If you say table names only contain letters, digits, and/or whitespace, then SQL injection is not possible, because you'll never be able to unquote the `[quoted table name]`.

Comment: That would be ideal if I had some control over the table names; unfortunately I do not.